# Image broken when render in Video Sequence Editor mode

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video and I want to add another audio to it by Blender. But when rendered it happened an error like the image below.
[image: Image broken]

And this is source video properties and rendering settings
[image: Video properties]

This error occurs with some image frame, not at all. What can I do?

Comment: Does it only happen when rendering or does it look this way sometimes as well when you scrub through your footage in the VSE? And what are your exact encoding settings?

Comment: thanks for your response, the problem happens even when i scrub through my footage in VSE. Furthermore, it only happens to some certain frames in that video, for another video is normal.
Change encoding when render is unsolved!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15853/2843

Comment: This method should help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843

Answer (score 2):

Speculating as we don't have enough information here to be conclusive, but this looks suspiciously like an issue with I / B / P frames.

Specifically, your in point on a sequence with B frames may not have enough information to fully build the frame as the decoder would need to decode both the previous I frame, but also the following I frame. If you have trimmed the strip to be in the middle of those I frames, you don't have enough information and you end up with that half broken frame.

Best advice, as usual, is to never use codecs for editing. Render to an intermediate frame sequence and use those as your footage inputs. This will also increase the quality of the work.

Comment: Your helping is useful, but I dont edit frames, I tried to add original video and render it without editing, unforturnaly, the problem is "alive".

Comment: Would need more information. If you render a full frame sequence from the original video, does it render properly? Using another tool like FFMPEG?

Answer (score 0):

I bet the Blender-included ffmpeg Codecs won't be able to decode your footage properly. It is mostly the case, when your footage is from a corrupted stream or the I- and B-Frames in your footage are inconsistent and you don't play it back frame by frame but jump between frames back and forth.

Probably you need a better Decoder for your footage like LSMASH (which worked really great for all footage I used so far where ffmpeg had issues). But it's pretty tricky to get it to work with Blender without reencoding your footage to an intermediate format which Blender can read properly. It's possible though with AviSynth and AFSmount with this LSMASH plugin.

So to get rid of this error with Blender try prefetching the whole Footage into your RAM or to render the whole Video without jumping between frames beforehand. (Maybe you have to Open your footage as a Movie Clip, prefetch it completely in the Movie Clip Editor and use it as a MovieClip Sequence in the VSE to make it work)

Comment: I added a description of how to do that: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843